# Combine two arrays to a multidimensional array pair in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have two arrays in the columns of mytable that I would like to combine to create a single multidimensional array.

| id | foo | bar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {1.2, 2.3, 3.5} | {0.01, 0.05, 0.6} |

Result:

| id | foobar |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {{1.2, 0.01}, {2.3, 0.05}, {3.5, 0.6}} |

@Erwin Brandstetter wrote the following function, but I am not sure how implement it for my stored arrays mytable.foo & mytable.bar.  I get an  error when I try an load the function:

`ERROR:  function array_cat(anyarray, anyarray) does not exist`

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg_mult (anyarray) (
   SFUNC    = array_cat
 , STYPE    = anyarray
 , INITCOND = '{}'
);
And use it like this:

SELECT array_agg_mult(ARRAY[ARRAY[a,b]]) AS foobar
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest(mytable.foo::float8[]) AS a
        , unnest(mytable.bar::float8[]) AS b
    ) x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query knits the arrays together as described in the original post:

```
WITH t(id, foo, bar) AS (
  VALUES (1, '{1.2, 2.3, 3.5}'::numeric[], '{0.01, 0.05, 0.6}'::numeric[]))
SELECT t.id, ARRAY_AGG(array[u.f, u.b]) AS foobar
  FROM t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.foo, t.bar) u(f, b)
  GROUP BY t.id;
```